# Bootstrap modal background

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How to display a background image when a modal is opened instead of the modal's overlay effect?
i tried adding css to the modal but the style applied only to the modal.
Code

```
<div class="modal hide" id="sourceModal" style="top: 95%; left: 50%;position:absolute;">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <div class="popup-header">
                <a class="close popup-close" onclick="closePopupnonmappedmodal();">×</a>
                <h3 class="medium" style="line-height: 35px;">
                   Information</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row-fluid" style="margin-top: 10px">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div id="Div3">
                       <p>Paste HTML of your landing page here.</p>
                       <p> Learn More. Learn More links to help article:</p>
                       <a href=" http://help.leadsquared.com/creating-landing-page-from-html"> http://help.leadsquared.com/creating-landing-page-from-html 
                       </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer" style="background-color: #efefef; text-align: center">
            <%: Html.CancelButton("ButtonCancel", onClick: "closePopupnonmappedmodal()", isDataDismiss: true)%>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You want to change the background overlay to an image ???

Comment: There will be an overlay div you can change the background of that div by adding background: /*Your Image*/ I dont know exactly which modal popup you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a background to `.modal`

All modals:

```
.modal {
    background: /* your background */
  }
```

Specific modal:

```
#myModal{
        background: /* your background */
      }
```

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/9J5LeUr5rF)

Comment: i want to add background only for this modal and not the other

Answer (score 1):

try this add '`!important`' to override default modal background style

```
.modal {
    background: url('imapge_path') !important;
  }
```